# blog display 3 images i need one,after every name and comment show up

Tags: php, css, count, blogs, display

blog display just one image from images folder,every time another image,after name and comment show up just like on this link           http://slimhamdi.net/lina/demos/blog-post-dark.html

```
enter code here

<?php 
   $image = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user3.jpg");
shuffle($image );
foreach($image  as $image ) {     
     echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
    echo '<img src="images/blog/'.$image.'">';
}  

?>

<img src="<?php echo "$image"; ?>" />
```

this is code to display an image

```
$sql = "SELECT  name, email,comment FROM blog1";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $count=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $count++;
    if($count==1){
    $count=0;
        echo '<img src="images/blog/'.$image.'">';
```

this code is to display image after name and comment show up in post every help will be appricate

Comment: Based on what what the link shows my guess is that you want to show the comment section based on a database. If this is your goal than you should add the user image in the comment/ blog1 table. This will make it a lot easier. The other possibility is to have a foreign key which can than access the image by join

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `name`, `email`, `comment` FROM `blog1`"; // Add backticks around table and column names to prevent MySQL reserved words error
$result = $conn->query( $sql );
$count = 0;
$images = array("user1.jpg", "user2.jpg", "user3.jpg"); // 

if( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    // output data of each row
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            echo '
                <div class="comment-block">
                    '.( !empty( $images[$count] ) ? '<img src="images/blog/'.$images[$count].'">' : '').' <!-- Add the count to the images to use it as a key, add check to see if count is a key -->
                    <span class="name">'.$row['name'].'</span>
                    <span class="comment">'.$row['comment'].'</span>
                </div>
            '; 

        $count++; // this usually goes at the end of a loop don't know if this produces the result you want
        if( $count == 3 )
        {
          $count = 0; // Reset to 0 if 3 images have been shown
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 69 in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\l\cv\blog-post-dark.php on line 621

Comment: @Mirza and what is line 621 this tells me nothing

Comment: same thing Undefined offset

Comment: @Mirza So in your script/ php file on line 621 it says `Undefined offset`? Or does it say `<img src="images/blog/'.$images[$count].'">`?

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 62 in C:\xampp\htdocs\h\l\cv\blog-post-dark.php on line 626
 dddddddd ddddddd  like this

Comment: @Mirza That is an error message. I don't think that on line 626, 621 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\h\l\cv\blog-post-dark.php is a complete error message as code

Comment: @Mirza see if the updated answers helps of not you just have to ask a new question

Comment: <img src="images/blog/'.$images[$count].'"> right here

Comment: @Mirza Finally... just look at the updated answer. It means there isn't an equal amount of comments and images

Comment: isn't an equal amount of comments and images that is right

Comment: should be like here http://slimhamdi.net/lina/demos/blog-post-dark.html

Comment: @Mirza and so you have to add a check to the image or it won't know what image to use as there is no key on the `$images` array that is equal to `$count`

Comment: i have 3 images in folder images what key i have put in

Comment: i put 0 but same image had displayed

Comment: image user1 .jpg is on i need one time display user1 next time user3 and then user3 after all 3 images will have displayed start all over again

Comment: @Mirza updated answer. You didn't made that clear in the question

Comment: it is comment it is not answer or qustion.Right now i have images displayed but just image user.1 .I need after image 1 for next comment next image.Can we chat some where.

Comment: I fixed but still has problem, images dont go where spouse to go.I need put images  on right place

Comment: I added class class="comment-avatar pull-left"  but still  not working ok.

Comment: @Mirza if the answer gave you the solution of how to get the name image and comment than that is your answer. If you than have another question about styling please ask a new question

Comment: Styling later now i have a problem same image is coming on.I want after third image will be display start over,start with image one.

Comment: I will ask new question.